# Is this axial load or radial load

Tags: forces

I am confused by Axial loading mentioned in the figure below. The long black line is a piece of rubber passing over different rollers. And at the point "Axial Load" a weight is attached. The rubber piece itself is drawn back and forth.

[image]

I believe this load attached is acting perpendicular to the axis of the rollers and the rubber piece movement so it's a radial load. Or am I wrong in my interpretation?

Comment: Axial to the rubber; it's a matter of relative to what.  In 3D cylindrical coordinate systems, the 3 axes can be considered axial, radial, and tangential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Abel said, this is axial to the rubber since the rubber is thin enough that you can assume that the force is passing through the centreline.
Also, for the rollers, yes the force is radial.
If there were friction, then there would be a tangential component to the rollers as well.